# Cron job doesn't read into the shell script function

Tags: bash, cron, sh

I'm having a strange situation where cron job is executing a script and doesn't read into the function. Yeah I know, solar flares.

On a serious note, the idea here that I have an `.sh` script which launches a scan of my environment. Below you can see the extract of it. The script successfully creates the output file and I can find this line `echo "Is this line parsed or not?" >> $output` in the output.
However, the next echo which is in the function `echo "I'm in the function!" >> $output` is not logged. The script stop on the function declaration and that's it.

I'm baffled. Any ideas?
Thanks!

```
.....
    touch $output
    # with this we are creating an empty file

    echo "Is this line parsed or not?" >> $output

    function do_the_scan() {
    # Load text file lines into a bash array.
    echo "I'm in the function!" >> $output
.....
```

Comment: Is your problem only when you call the script from cron or also when you launch it manually ?

Comment: only from the cron. The script goes perfectly when launched manually.

Comment: At a *guess*, your script relies on one or more [bashisms](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) and `cron` is running it with `dash`. But it's impossible to say for sure given the lack of relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function declaration syntax is wrong. You should use:

```
do_the_scan() {
    # Load text file lines into a bash array.
    echo "I'm in the function!" >> $output
}
```

…unless the script is run in Bash since `function` is a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism).

This is a demonstration of the error in an interactive shell:

```
> sh
$ function bar() {
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$
```

Anyway, you should capture the error output of your script using a [standard error output redirection](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-redirect-error-output-to-file/) (e.g. `2> err.log`). Put it directly on the command’s line in the crontab, so it can capture the errors produced by the interpreter of the script.

### See also

- https://www.shellscript.sh/functions.html
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged